# Find the global maximum and global minimum

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$ f(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 - 15x + 8 $ for the interval $ [-2,6] $

My answer was :

$$ f'(x) = 3(x^2-4x-5) $$
$$ 3(x-5)(x+1) $$

so the critical points are $ x =5\; and \;x=-1 $

plugging them back with the end points into the original function

$$f(5) = 5^2 - 6(5)^2 - 15(5) +8 = -92 $$

$$ f(-1) = 16 $$

$$ f(-2) =6 $$

$$ f(6) = -82 $$

so i got the min is $-92$ and max is $16$ but the answer in the book says the min is $5$ and max is $-1$

Comment: What is wrong here?!

Comment: I don't know, it's weird. The book says the right answer is min at $ x=5 $ and max at $ x=-1 $

Comment: Nothing is wrong???

Comment: You have a minimum of $-92$ when $x=5$ and maximum of $16$ when $x=-1$.  So going by the last comment, you and the book are both saying the same thing.  So what is the problem?

Comment: yeah sorry i just got confused a little bit. sorry

Comment: f(5) = (5)^3 - ... instead of (5)^2

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Hint: You are almost right!
Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima

The global maxima is **different** than the maximum value of the function $f(x)$. It is the value of $x$ which maximizes $f(x)$, not the maximum value itself.

Comment: What am i wrong at ?

Comment: The global maxima is DIFFERENT from the maximum value of the function $f(x)$; it is the value of $x$ which maximizes $f(x)$ @Tennisman

Comment: Ahhh yeah :) iam stupid. Thank you